# Install PHP7 from Remi repo

Tags: php, centos6

I installed PHP7 from Remi repo with

```
sudo yum -y install httpd
sudo yum -y install epel-release
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm 
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm
sudo yum -y --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install php70
scl enable php70 'php -v'
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php70 /usr/bin/php
```

and it is working via CLI. Now I want to make it work with apache but i can't find a so to pass as a second argument to LoadModule

```
LoadModule php7_module        unknown_path  
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Is this the correct approach to make PHP7 to work with apache2?

Comment: http://php7.zend.com/install-ubuntu.php  It's for Centos7 but it may help.

Comment: I ended up writing https://blog.nexcess.net/2015/07/21/install-wordpress-with-php-7/ with the Zend PHP7 builds.

Comment: PHP7, given its pre-release status, seems like it falls solidly in the "unsupported software" close category.

Comment: `find / -iname '*php*.so'` :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default "php70" (Software Collection) don't install the mod_php.

```
yum install php70-php
```

And check you haven't any other mod_php (such as the one provided by "php" base package)

Comment: Hi Remi.  I just installed on centos 6.7 (`yum install php70-php-pear  php70-php-bcmath  php70-php-pecl-jsond-devel  php70-php-mysqlnd  php70-php-gd  php70-php-common  php70-php-fpm  php70-php-intl  php70-php-cli  php70-php  php70-php-xml  php70-php-opcache  php70-php-pecl-apcu  php70-php-pecl-jsond  php70-php-pdo  php70-php-gmp  php70-php-process  php70-php-pecl-imagick  php70-php-devel  php70-php-mbstring`) and while the install worked flawlessly my sites are still being served in php 5.6.  How do I "switch" nginx over to php 7?

Comment: Since fcgi passes over 127.0.0.1:9000 I assume I need to somehow disable 5.6 on that port and make it be php 7 instead... but my mind's gone blank!  I'm guessing that if I uninstalled all of the 5.6 stuff first, and then installed 7, that would also resolve it?

Comment: If you nedd a single php version, you can disable "php-fpm" and use "php70-php-fpm" instead. If you need both, change the listen option in the pool definition, and nginx configuration.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  For anyone else in the same boat this does the trick:  `service php-fpm stop`, `service php70-php-fpm start`.  You'll find php.ini and php-fpm conf files in `/etc/opt/remi/php70/` rather than just in `etc`.

Comment: @RemiCollet I installed php 5.6 using remo repos. Know how can I upgrade 5.6 to 7? I need only one version. Thansk.

Comment: @RemiCollet does `php70-php` work with httpd24 ?  I'm getting conflict errors when trying to install it on an aws server with (only) httpd24 installed ? (it's requesting httpd as a dependency rather than httpd24)

Comment: It works with "httpd" in base system.  But if you use httpd24, you probably don't need "mod_php", rather use php-fpm (SetHandler to proxy is supported in recent versions)

Answer (score 6):

FYI for those looking to install PHP 7 using the `remi-php70` repository (now that PHP 7.0.0 has been released), you can install packages using the same package names you know and love, for example:

- `php`
- `php-cli`
- `php-common`
- `php-devel`
- `php-fpm`
- `php-gd`
- `php-mbstring`
- `php-pdo`
- etc.

Comment: How? php54 seems to be the default with remi-release-7.rpm?

Comment: @giorgio79 if you enable `remi-php70.repo` and disable all other php versions from the remi repos, running `yum install php-fpm` by default uses 7.0, but this does NOT work with 7.1 (or other future releases)

Comment: My finding is: if more than one repository is configured in /etc/yum.repos.d that offers a particular php package, I get whatever the 1st installed (alphabetically) repository offers and to install other versions from the REMI repositories I must explicitly state the release, e.g. `yum install php74` instead of `php`.  Once I remove all repositories but the one containing the release I want (in this case, `remi-php74`), running `yum install php` not only installs php from remi-php74, but also configures it as `/usr/bin/php` instead of `/usr/bin/php74.`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else trying to upgrade from PHP 5.6 to 7.0.1 on Centos 6.7:

I managed to get this working today almost like @mbalparda has listed but without using epel-release (though a few epel repos are enabled and in use)

I had php 5.6 from IUS (https://ius.io/GettingStarted/) repo (https://centos6.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm) installed, so I removed them by:

```
# yum list installed | grep php5
php56u.x86_64          5.6.14-1.ius.centos6
php56u-cli.x86_64      5.6.14-1.ius.centos6
php56u-common.x86_64   5.6.14-1.ius.centos6
...
```

and so

```
# yum erase php56u php56u-cli php56u-common php56u-mcrypt php56u-mysqlnd ...
```

followed by the listed commands:

```
# wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm 
# rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm
# yum install php70-php php70-php-cli php70-php-common php70-php-mcrypt php70-php-mysqlnd ...
# scl enable php70 'php -v'
# sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php70 /usr/bin/php
# service httpd restart
```

Comment: mixing php70-* and php56u-* package in the same command seems very strange. Probably unwanted. And if you want a single version, using the SCL is not the simplest solution.  Simplest is to enable remi-php70 repository and "yum update". Remember to try the new wizard: http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: @RemiCollet thanks for pointing out the typo, edited the post to reflect the same - I meant to write php70-php-mysqlnd etc but copy-pasted / edited wrongly ... Also, the wizard seems superb. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me to downgrade from PHP 7.2 to PHP 7.0

Answer (score 2):

PHP70 also seems to install everything under /etc/opt/remi/php70/:

you'll need to run:

```
source /opt/remi/php70/enable
```

Comment: You should elaborate. Why do you need to run that? What does it do? How does it help the OP find the Apache module?

Comment: If PHP 7 still doesn't work you'll need to run it to make it work. It will add a line in apache to load the php70 module.

Comment: this will stop working if you logout and log back in. this is the problem i am facing.

Comment: What the heck this one burned me on my 7.4 install! Added the PATH entries as needed and it's working. Sheesh no idea why it was designed like that!

Answer (score 1):

If you have older php version (like 5.6) installed, don't forget to do something like this:

```
cd /etc/httpd/conf.d/
mv php.conf php.conf.dis
```

Restart apache and that should do it.

Comment: Strangely, this solution fixed it for me after a few hours of mumbling around.