# PHP 7 conflicts with PHP 5 (Centos 7)

Tags: centos, php, yum, centos7

Trying to install PHP 7 now that it's available;

(on centos 7)

added repo's:

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
Then installed via:

yum install php70w php70w-opcache
```

Output is:

```
[root@host]# yum install php70w php70w-opcache
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
* epel: mirror.symnds.com
* extras: mirror.netdepot.com
* updates: mirrors.rit.edu
* webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70w.x86_64 0:7.0.2-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php70w-common(x86-64) = 7.0.2-1.w7 for package: php70w-7.0.2-1.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php70w-cli(x86-64) = 7.0.2-1.w7 for package: php70w-7.0.2-1.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php70w-cli = 7.0.2-1.w7 for package: php70w-7.0.2-1.w7.x86_64
---> Package php70w-opcache.x86_64 0:7.0.2-1.w7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70w-cli.x86_64 0:7.0.2-1.w7 will be installed
---> Package php70w-common.x86_64 0:7.0.2-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.2-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So the problem is : `Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64`

How to fix this? I need both versions running simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install php7 for C7 (and others) as a Software Collection (scl) This installs alongside the system provided php 5 and is entirely independent of it. You can find the php7 scl on the [REMI repo](http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/03/25/PHP-7.0-as-Software-Collection). You may also be interested in this [Q&A on SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/706349/install-php7-from-remi-repo).

Comment: See the configuration Wizard on http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is the good way. It is very ornate to configuration and to program if you have to different PHP versions on one server. It's much easier if you have a separate server. Also why do you need both? PHP 5 app are pretty much compatible to PHP 7... if they use mysql_connect instead of mysqli

Comment: I must disagree. Running various versions on the same box is very useful. Especially to test app before upgrading prod. And this is very easy using various FPM instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command

```
yum --skip-broken install (package_name)
```

It will install all the dependencies and skip conflicting packages.